# Trying to get plist data from server but getting nothing

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, plist

i am building this app in which i need to get data from server here is my code

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://URL/ios/jobsearch.php"];
NSDictionary *dataDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        OriginalResultArray=[dataDict valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        jobResultArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [jobResultArray addObjectsFromArray:OriginalResultArray];
        NSLog(@"Result is : %@",jobResultArray);
```

and here is my jobsearch.php

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Objects</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>jobname</key>
<string>asdfasdf111</string>
<key>jobbids</key>
<integer>3</integer>
<key>jobpay</key>
<integer>$30</integer>
<key>jobid</key>
<integer>3</integer>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>jobname</key>
<string>asdfasdf1111111333</string>
<key>jobbids</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>jobpay</key>
<integer>$36</integer>
<key>jobid</key>
<integer>5</integer>
</dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

with all this code i am getting noting in return. There are 2 Dict in my php file if you see and every dict have 4 keys in it. if i remove 2 keys from every dict and have only 2 keys so in that case i do get data in my array. but i need all 4 keys with data. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: your .plist data is not in right format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The data isn't in right format.***

[image]

*Change*

```
<key>jobpay</key>
<integer>$30</integer>
```

*to*

```
<key>jobpay</key>
<string>$30</string>
```

***Now data is in right format.***

[image]

***Below is the complete data.***

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Objects</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>jobname</key>
            <string>asdfasdf111</string>
            <key>jobbids</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>jobpay</key>
            <string>$30</string>
            <key>jobid</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>jobname</key>
            <string>asdfasdf1111111333</string>
            <key>jobbids</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>jobpay</key>
            <string>$36</string>
            <key>jobid</key>
            <integer>5</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

***Final Output:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use TBXml parser. This is the easiest way to parse XML data.

You can download it in [Github link](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML)